# Expand multiple dropdown menus using a href link

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, href, dropdown

In my header nav, I have 3 dropdown toggles which I am hoping to be able to expand by allow the user to click on a `href` link?

Here is my dropdown Nav code:

```
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="fa fa-question-circle fa-fw"></i> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</a>

<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-alerts">
    <div class="" style="overflow-y: scroll;height:385px;width:350px; padding-left:0.5cm">
        <b>Support</b> Tickets
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li>
            <a class="text-center" href="messages.php?show=support">
                <strong>See All Open Tickets</strong><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
            </a>
        </li> 
    </div>
</ul>
```

Is there a way I can open this when a user clicks a link located somewhere else on the page, such as:

`<a href="#dropdown-toggle">Open Dropdown</a>`

Or something similar?

Comment: Are you using any Javascript libraries like JQuery or Bootstrap? There's absolutely a way but it depends on how the dropdown works in the first place

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't mention it, both JQuery and Bootstrap are being used and this dropdown menu is a Bootstrap style menu.

Comment: Look at the [Bootstrap Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns) for dropdowns, you can either use HTML or Javascript to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks a little strange, but I'll just give you a general idea.

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="open">Open Dropdowns</a>
```

JS

```
$('#open').onclick(function(){
    $('.dropdown-toggle').click();
});
```

What the javascript does is that, when you click on an element with the ID "open", it will simulate a click on **all** elements with the class "dropdown-toggle". This is the easy method, hopefully this will work for you.