# How to expand a dropdown using a link from a different page

Tags: html, jquery, dropdown

I've been tasked with creating a landing page for my company that will house hundreds of job aid PDF documents.  to make the content more manageable, I've placed the docs in dropdowns using aria-controls. Additionally, there will be various inbound links pointing to specific documents on the page. With all the documents hidden in dropdowns (and having the dropdowns collapsed out of necessity), end users will find it difficult to locate the desired document. Adding anchor links won't help as the documents will be hidden in the dropdown.

I'd like to see if there's a way to expand a desired dropdown using the inbound link. I believe it may involve jquery and i will need some help.  this thread came close ([Expand multiple dropdown menus using a href link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34662341/expand-multiple-dropdown-menus-using-a-href-link)) but in this case the link was on the same page, not on a completely different page.  I couldn't find a way to apply it to my problem. We'll call this page https://example.com/test. The code below works, I just need to add to it to expand a desired dropdown.  for example, an inbound link would be:

```
<a href="https://example.com/test#doc1" target="_blank">Link to item 1 in dropdown 1</a>
```

Here's the code:

```
<script>$( document ).ready(function() {

 $( "#collapsebutton" ).hide();

  $( "#expandbutton" ).click(function() {
  $('div.panel-collapse').addClass('in').css("height", "");
  $( "#expandbutton" ).hide();
  $( "#collapsebutton" ).show();
  });

  $( "#collapsebutton" ).click(function() {
  $('div.panel-collapse').removeClass('in');
  $( "#expandbutton" ).show();
  $( "#collapsebutton" ).hide();
  });

  $( "div.panel a" ).click(function() {
    $('div.panel-collapse').each(function( index ) {
      if($( this ).hasClass('in') ){
      $( "#expandbutton" ).show();
      $( "#collapsebutton" ).hide();
      }
    });
  });

});</script>

<!-- Begin Expand/collapse all button -->
<div class="nodisp expandcollapse btn btn-small btn-success no-print" id="collapsebutton" style="margin: 10px 0px; float:right;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i> Collapse All</div>

<div class="disp expandcollapse btn btn-small btn-success no-print" id="expandbutton" style="margin: 10px 0px; float:right;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Expand All</div>
<!-- End Expand/Collapse all Button-->

<div aria-multiselectable="true" class="panel-group" id="section1" role="tablist">

<!-- Begin Dropdown 1 -->
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" id="headingOne" role="tab" style="background-color:#ececf1">
    <h4 class="panel-title"><a aria-controls="collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" role="button"><b>Dropdown 1</b><i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-fw"></i></a></h4>
    </div>

    <div aria-labelledby="headingOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapseOne" role="tabpanel">
        <div class="panel-body">
        <ul>
            <li id="doc1">Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
            
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End Dropdown 1 -->

<!-- Begin Dropdown 2 -->
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" id="headingTwo" role="tab" style="background-color:#ececf1">
    <h4 class="panel-title"><a aria-controls="collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo" role="button"><b>Dropdown 2</b><i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-fw"></i></a></h4>
    </div>

    <div aria-labelledby="headingTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapseTwo" role="tabpanel">
        <div class="panel-body">
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End Dropdown 2 --> 
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a dropdown menu linked to a completely other page you need to change the following line:

```
<li>item 1</li>
```

to:

```
<li><a href="#">Name</a></li>
```

The "#" represents the link to another page, for example: [www.google.nl](http://www.google.nl), or [www.example.com/doc1](http://www.example.com/doc1).

Comment: Hi Mike, i'm looking for an inbound link to expand a selected dropdown on the destination page.  I'm not sure it's possible, but maybe with jquery?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if that's possible. Maybe you can look up some video's from Dev Ed, he helps me a lot tho